# Given the support function of a convex set $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, compute $\sup \left \{c'y: (x,y) \in C\right\}$ as a function of $x$

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, support-function

Suppose $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is a closed, bounded, convex set, with support function $h: \mathbb{R}^{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined as
$$h(c_1, c_2) := \sup \{c_1'x + c_2'y : (x,y) \in C\}~.$$

If all I know about $C$ is its support function (in a sense, this means I "know" $C$ itself), is it possible to obtain a reasonable expression for
$$H_c(x) := \sup \left\{c'y: (x,y) \in C\right\}~,$$
for a known $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
ideally in terms of the support function $h$? What if I also know the $\arg\sup$? (not sure what this function is called):
$$s(c_1, c_2) := \arg\sup \{c_1'x + c_2'y : (x,y) \in C\}~.$$

I am especially interested in computing the quantity $\sup_{x \in C_x} \frac{H_c(x)}{c'x}$ (assume that $C$ bounds $x$ away from zero) where $C_x$ is the projection of $C$ onto it's first $n$ coordinates. We can, of course, obtain $\sup_{x \in C_x} H_c(x) = h(0,c)$, but it's not clear to me how to translate this to obtain $\sup_{x} \frac{H_c(x)}{c'x}$.